# Checking the index of a csv file in python

Tags: python, csv, indexing

I need to find a way that the csv file will place the input on the highest index. For instance I got three rows filled with information now it has to start placing the input on the 4th row however I don't know how to do this.

Here is my code, which you can also find on [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/4FTKM5Ep):

```
__author__ = 'mar'

import csv
csvbestand="project.csv"

#This part is supposed to find the highest index
def indexchk():
    global index

    try:
        f = open(csvbestand, 'r')
        reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=';')
        for i in csvbestand:

    except:
        print("lukt niet")

    finally:
        f.close()

#Here you can put your input which is then placed in the csv document. Now it needs to be put in a different row then the previous ones.
def user():
    try:
        f = open(csvbestand, 'a', newline='')
        writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter=';')
        #writer.writerow( ('Voornaam(s)', 'Achternaam', 'Geboortedatum', 'E-mailadres') )
        writer.writerow((index),(input("Voornaam(s): "),input("Achternaam: "),input("Geboortedatum: "),input("E-mailadres: ")))
    except BaseException:
            print("fout, kan bestand niet openen")

    finally:
        f.close()

indexchk()
user()
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as you open your file to `append` as opposed to `write`, any new lines will be written after the last line in your file.

Your code correctly opens the file to `append` so you should be able to add additional rows without first having to explicitly identify the last row.

Append any new lines:

```
f = open(csvbestand, 'a')
```

Overwrite the whole file:

```
f = open(csvbestand, 'w')
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand well you try to write in a csv file at the end of it (since its last row within)?

```
yourfile = open('project.csv','a')
yourfile.write(TheStuffYouWantToWrite)
yourfile.close()
```

[Here a summary of file manipulation](http://rgruet.free.fr/PQR27/PQR2.7.html#files)